# ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details

Tags: javascript, html, http, firefox, webrtc

Im trying to find client Ip address using WebRTC, but in firefox im getting this error :

**ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details**

```
     var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            var pc = new myPeerConnection({ iceServers: [
   { url: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478", username: "my@gmail.com", "credential": "xxxxxx" },
   { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }


] }),
                noop = function () { },
                localIPs = {},
                ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
                key;
            function ipIterate(ip) {
                if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
                localIPs[ip] = true;
            }
            pc.createDataChannel("");
            pc.createOffer(function (sdp) {
                sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
                    if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
                    line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
                });
                pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
            }, noop);
            pc.onicecandidate = function (ice) {
                if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
                ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
            };
```

log in about:webrtc:

[image: about:webrtc]

ICE Relay log

0.009   rtp host    3350409123  udp e6e7f092-e632-4986-97b2-90b20c3b15cd.local  59923   126 | 30 | 255
0.062   rtp srflx   842163049   udp IP  59923   100 | 30 | 255
0.313   rtp relay   453802058   udp IP  57652   2 | 30 | 255
0.313   Done
0.315

Comment: anyone? it seems that turn servers are not free.. and firefox for some reason require turn server?

Comment: Could you try to retrieve your ICE relay Candidate using [this website](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)?

Comment: Yes, I am adding the log into main question

Comment: wierd thing is.. when i open the page I get this error.. but when I click back from previous page to this..so postback  is works fine

Comment: Ok, so your TURN seems to work because the browser retrieves its relay candidate. Note that your public IP is present and you may want remove it from your post. Just a detail, you should maybe add an 's' at the `url` attribute (the first `iceServers` value)

Comment: Doesnt work even with s added

Comment: Hello, have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by some "privacy" addons (for example, the **"Prevent WebRTC from leaking local IP addresses"** setting of ublock could cause this problem). So, make sure the value of `media.peerconnection.ice.proxy_only` in `about:config` is not set to `true`

Comment: Not working, same situation

Answer (score 0):

go to `about:webrtc` in firefox and tap clear history and clear log. in my case that's work for me